# Laravel 4 - Seems there is a Bug

Tags: laravel-4

When i do the syntax check for the laravel files i am getting the error in the following file. Please some one help me on this.

```
php -l vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/iconv.php

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare iconv() in vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/iconv.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions defined in iconv.php are implementations of native php functions. The file iconv.php is only used when iconv was not compiled with php.

You will see this same type of error when you run

- `php -l Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/mbstring.php`
- `php -l Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/utf8_encode.php`
- `php -l Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/intl.php`

If you want to remove the error, you can recompile php without iconv([instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php)). But you really shouldn't do that. Just remove these 4 files from your syntax checking script.